# Linq to Entities timeout issues

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ria

So I have the following linq query that times out when the foreach loop enumerates the data:

```
public IQueryable<Client> GetTopLevelData(Guid agentGuid, int year)
    {
        var clients = from client in ObjectContext.Clients
                join cbc in ObjectContext.Client_Bucket_Client on client.Client_GUID equals cbc.Client_GUID
                join acb in ObjectContext.Agent_Client_Bucket on cbc.Client_Bucket_GUID equals acb.Client_Bucket_GUID
                where acb.Agent_GUID == agentGuid
                orderby client.Last_Change_Date descending, client.File_Under 
                select client;

        var clientInfos =
            from c in clients
            select new
            {
                Client = c,
                TransactionInfos = ObjectContext.Transactions
                    .Where(t => t.Client_GUID == c.Client_GUID && t.Year == year)
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        Transaction = t,
                        ToAttach = ObjectContext.Forms.Where(f => f.Transaction_GUID == t.Transaction_GUID && f.Year == year) //.OrderByDescending(fo => fo.Create_Date);
                    })
            };

        // Looping over this query will hit the database *once*
        foreach (var info in clientInfos)
        {
            foreach (var transactionInfo in info.TransactionInfos)
            {
                transactionInfo.Transaction.Forms.Attach(transactionInfo.ToAttach);
            }

            var tt = info.TransactionInfos.ToList(); //.Select(t => t.Transaction);

            var trans = tt.Select(t => t.Transaction);

            info.Client.Transactions.Attach(trans);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timeout in your [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords).

```
"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=northwind;server=mySQLServer;Connect Timeout=30";
```

The `Connect Timeout` is in seconds

Comment: Thanks Kim! I added the Connect Timeout and set to 120 and it worked! Seems that, at least on my system, the default is 15 seconds.  This being the time it usually ran before throwing an exception when the Connect Timeout parameter was not in the connection string.

Comment: @Ruggeri no problem :) its default 15 seconds on all systems.